Given a cone and plane, how to find the centers and points of tangencies of the Dandelin spheres?
Given a cone and a plane intersecting it, construct the Dandelin spheres, and find their centers points of tangency to the cone and plane.
My work so far below.

Work so far
Let's start in two dimensions.  Take a cross section of the cone which includes its axis of symmetry.  Label the apex of the cone $P$, the two rays in the cross section $PA, PB$, and the intersection of the plane and the rays $L,R$.

The upper "Dandelin circle" is then the incenter of $\triangle PLR$, since the incircle is tangent to each of these three lines, and we find its center as the point of concurrency of the three angle bisectors.  For the same reason, the lower Dandelin circle is the point of concurrency of the angle bisectors of $\angle ALR, \angle BRL, \angle LPR$.

The points of tangency to the rays are the points $X_1, Z_1, X_2, Z_2$ where these circles intersect the rays, and the points of tangency to the line $LR$ are $Y_1, Y_2$.

Now, what happens when we move to three dimensions by rotating the rays about the cone's axis? Each circle sweeps out a sphere, and $X_1, Z_1, X_2, Z_2$ sweep out circles on the cone. By symmetry, each of these circles remains tangent to its respective sphere.
However, the circles swept out by $Y_1, Y_2$ are not (generally) on the plane, and indeed these points are not (generally) tangent to the spheres! They'll only be tangent if the plane is perpendicular to the line from the sphere's center to the plane, and this isn't guaranteed.
This boils down to: The above construction starts with a cross section of the cone that includes the cone's axis.  But unless the plane is perpendicular to the cone's axis, each of these cross sections will look different.  Only one will even include the point of tangency, but it's not at clear how we even find it.

Solution! Verification requested.
Inspired by the responses, here is the solution.  I've added the proof-verification tag to request verification or improvements.
Call the cone's axis of symmetry $s$ and the plane which cuts the cone $\kappa$.  There is a unique plane $\sigma$ which includes $s$ and is perpendicular to $\kappa$.  Perform the construction as above, fixing the cone's cross section in plane $\sigma$; then line $LR$ will be the intersection of $\kappa$ and $\sigma$.
We've already shown that at point $Y_1$, line $LR$ is tangent to the upper circle.  We now show that at $Y_1$,  plane $\kappa$​ is tangent to the upper sphere.
Let line $k$ be the unique line in $\kappa$ that is perpendicular to $LR$ at $Y_1$.  We have two planes $\kappa$ and $\sigma$,  perpendicular and intersecting in line $LR$.  Then any two lines, one in $\kappa$ and one in $\sigma$, each perpendicular to $LR$, must be perpendicular to each other if they meet.  The lines $I_1Y_1$ and $k$ meet these conditions, and so $I_1Y_1 \perp k$.
Since $I_1Y_1$ is perpendicular to two distinct lines in $\kappa$ (namely $LR$ and $k$), it is perpendicular to $\kappa$, and $\kappa$ is therefore tangent to the upper sphere.  A similar argument works for the lower sphere, completing the construction.

I may be missing the point of your question, but ... Introduce any plane perpendicular to the cone's axis; this plane intersects the cutting plane in an appropriate "sight-line": projecting onto a plane perpendicular to that line gives your construction figures. Coord-wise, the direction vector of the sight-line is the cross product of the planes' normal vectors —ie, the normal vector of the plane and the direction vector of the axis. (If the plane is perpendicular to the axis, then sighting along any direction perpendicular to the axis will do.)

@Blue What is a "sight-line"?

"What is a "sight-line"?" "Sight-line" is a figurative description of a direction of orthogonal projection into a plane. (Eg, the $y$-axis is a sight-line onto the $xz$-plane.) If two planes intersect in a line $\ell$, viewing along "sight-line" $\ell$ makes the planes themselves look like lines; ie, projecting into a plane perpendicular to $\ell$ turns the planes into lines, and turns $\ell$ into their point of intersection. The sight-line I describe in my earlier comment turns a cone-and-plane-and-Dandelin-spheres configuration into your lines-and-inscribed-circles figures.

If a sphere is tangent to a plane at $Y$, then the line joining $Y$ with the center of the sphere is perpendicular to the plane. Hence lines $Y_1I_1$ and $Y_2I_2$ are both perpendicular to the tangent plane, and parallel between them. The plane containing lines $Y_1I_1$ and $Y_2I_2$ is thus perpendicular to the tangent plane, and it also contains the axis of the cone. This is plane you need to consider.

Your construction looks fine to me. You should only note that "There is a unique plane  which includes  and is perpendicular to ." is true only if $\kappa$ is not perpendicular to $s$.

The "verification requested" part looks fine to me, too. (As well as the rest of the construction.)

We need to deal with two planes for this problem, so let's give them names.
Let $\pi_0$ be the plane mentioned in the problem statement,
so that the Dandelin spheres were are seeking will be tangent to $\pi_0$.
Select your cross-sectional plane $\pi_1$ so that it passes through the axis of the cone and is perpendicular to $\pi_0$. Then $L$ and $R$ are on the cone and on both planes $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$.
Then proceed with your construction as you described it.
In the end, the spheres are generated by rotating the circles around the axis of the cone, but the plane $\pi_0$ is already known to be perpendicular to the plane $\pi_1$ in which your cross-section is constructed,
therefore the line $I_1Y_1$, which is perpendicular to the intersection of the planes $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$ and lies in the plane $\pi_1$, is perpendicular to $\pi_0$; similarly for $I_2Y_2$; therefore $\pi_0$ is tangent to the two spheres.
The circles generated by rotating $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ around the axis are completely irrelevant since the plane $\pi_0$ is not rotationally symmetric about that axis. No part of either circle (except the points $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ themselves) lies in the plane $\pi_0$.

Thanks.  I'm having trouble seeing how this shows $I_1Y_1 \perp \pi_0$.  Can you elaborate on that or perhaps draw a diagram?

Since we have not assigned coordinates to this space, assign them this way: Let $Y_1Y_2$ be the $x$ axis with the origin at $Y_1$. Therefore $I_1Y_1$ is on the $y$ axis. Therefore $\pi_1$ is the $x,y$ plane. Now the $x,z$ plane is perpendicular to $\pi_1$ (the $x,y$ plane) and intersects $\pi_1$ along the $x$ axis. But there's only one plane that is perpendicular to $\pi_1$ and intersects $\pi_1$ along the $x$ axis, and that plane is $\pi_0$. Therefore $\pi_0$ is the $x,z$ plane and is perpendicular to the $y$ axis and $I_1Y_1$.

Thanks.  Your answer helped me work out the construction in detail - could you take a look at my write up?
